# Evince show annotation text in preview instead of page, author and date

Tags: pdf, evince, previews, annotation

I am using evince for viewing PDFs and I use highlight and note annotations quite a bit. My evince version is `GNOME Document Viewer 3.36.0`. As shown in the image below, the annotations are previewed by page number and then author and date.

[image: Annotation sidebar]

A preview showing the annotation text (if any) is much more helpful in immediately understanding the context. Is there anyway to change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is how it has been programmed to work. You may want to file this as an issue to the developpers so they may consider revising this in a future version.

Comment: Can you point me to the appropriate forum? Also do you know if the team is readily accepting features? Thanks.